# Frontend and Backend menu not clickable in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, menu, magento-2.0

After installation of stable Magento 2.0, everything seemed to work fine but not the menus (frontend & backend - menu not clickable).

Further investigation showed 404 error for `static/_requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js` file even though the file was there.

My nginx conf file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name magento2.dev;
    set $MAGE_ROOT  /path/to/magento2;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    include /path/to/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: this is already awell known issue = you have either permissions or rewrite wrong .

Comment: You try switch to production mode when run bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Comment: It seems to be the file permission issue. Other permission didn't work for me except 777 which I always try to avoid :)

Comment: try to run this command bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: if only chmod 777 works it means you have wrong user:group in php/nginx